# A text file to output conversion in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a file where there are say `n` columns. Where the first `n-1` columns represent the value of the `n-1` attributes and the `n`-th column represent the value of the `class` for a particular dataset. Now I want to first read that dataset and print a single line as output where it will print `n-1` comma separated `*` and then at the `n`th column, the class with the maximum frequency will come and sit. For an example suppose I have a file `dataset1.data` which contains :

```
12,13,14,44,0
11,11,10,34,0
22,54,98,11,2
34,90,78,90,1
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,0
34,90,78,90,2
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,2
34,90,78,90,2
44,34,34,33,2
```

For the above case the output will be: `*,*,*,*,2` because class 2 has the highest frequency.

And in case of tie in the highest frequency count, it will take the minimum class value.

For an example:

```
    12,13,14,44,0
    11,11,10,34,0
    22,54,98,11,2
    34,90,78,90,1
    44,34,34,33,1
    22,54,98,11,0
    34,90,78,90,2
    44,34,34,33,1
    22,54,98,11,2
```

In this case the output will be : `*,*,*,*,0` because here all the class have the same frequency.

How can I do it? Can anyone help please!

Comment: I suggest you keep a dictionary with the counts of each class while reading the lines from the file. What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to read your file with pandas and then use value_counts(). It will give you the count of each class and then you can sort and write the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

cls_counts = Counter()
with open('dataset1.data') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = list(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
        attrs, cls = row[:-1], row[-1]
        cls_counts[cls] += 1
max_cls_val = max(cls_counts.values())
max_cls_keys = [cls for cls, count in cls_counts.items() if count == max_cls_val]
print(f"{'*,' * len(attrs)}{min(max_cls_keys)}")
```

#### **Example Usage 1, Unique class with max count:**

`dataset1.data`:

```
12,13,14,44,0
11,11,10,34,0
22,54,98,11,2
34,90,78,90,1
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,0
34,90,78,90,2
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,2
34,90,78,90,2
44,34,34,33,2
```

**Output:**

```
*,*,*,*,2
```

#### **Example Usage 2, Multiple classes with max count:**

`dataset1.data`:

```
12,13,14,44,0
11,11,10,34,0
22,54,98,11,2
34,90,78,90,1
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,0
34,90,78,90,2
44,34,34,33,1
22,54,98,11,2
```

**Output:**

```
*,*,*,*,0
```